# WordPress admin ajax not working correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this PHP page in my WordPress plugin settings page:

```
<input type="button" class="button button-primary" onclick="update(<?php echo $id; ?>)" value="Done">
```

This is my JS function which gets called on button click:

```
function update(id) {

        jQuery('.table100 .blockUI').removeClass('invisible');

        var data = {
            'action': 'update_table',
            'id': id
        };

        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function () {
        }).success(function () {
            location.reload();
        }).fail(function (data) {
            jQuery('.table100 .blockUI').addClass('invisible');
            alert('An error occured during the database update!');
        });
    }
```

This is the function which should be executed when the js functions gets executed:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_table', 'update_table' );
function update_table() {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    global $wpdb;

    if ( $id > 0 && ! empty( $id ) ) {
        $result = $wpdb->update( 'my_table', array( 'xyz' => '1' ), array( 'id' => $id ) );

        if ( empty( $result ) ) {
            wp_send_json_error( null, 400 );
            wp_die();
        }

    } else {
        header( 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error' );
        header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' );
        die( json_encode( array(
            'message' => 'ERROR. Id missing. Can not update my_table.',
            'code'    => 1337
        ) ) );
    }
}
```

All three parts are at the same page and I've tried to trigger it but I'm always getting 400 Bad Request issue. I've added a debug to the PHP function to find out if the function gets called but no result.

**My goal:**
My goal is it to update a value in the database where id = submitted id.

Comment: Chrome and logged in. As i know an access to the admin page is not possible when an admin user is not logged in.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I re-read your question and you did mention that you're doing this on a custom plugin's settings page. I tried your code on a test plugin with a few minor modifications (stripped out some code, like your DB queries) and it worked for me just fine, though. No error 400.

Comment: Is it possible that the row in your DB is already correct? From the WP docs: '_Keep in mind that if the $data matches what is already in the database, no rows will be updated, so 0 will be returned. Because of this, you should probably check the return with false === $result_'.

Comment: So finally I found the problem. I can't add this function on the same page. I moved it to the functions.php and now it works.